# SQL query for count employee gender

Tags: sql

The question is: For each publisher list the publisher name and the number of male and the number of female employees employed by the publisher. The SQL statement should display the result in the following format:

```
Publishername    Male    Female
Academic            4   0
Ace Books           4   3
Oxford Press        0   4
```

The employee table to take info from is:

```
EMPNO LNAME                GENDER PUBLISHERNAME        SUPEREMPNO
----- -------------------- ------ -------------------- ----------
E1    Black                M      Pearson
E2    Clark                M      Pearson              E1
E3    Bean                 M      Pearson              E1
E4    Cassidy              M      Pearson              E1
E5    Smith                F      Elsevier
E6    Jones                F      Elsevier             E3
E7    Smith                F      Elsevier             E3
E8    West                 F      Elsevier             E3
E9    Smith                M      Planeta
E10   Love                 M      Planeta              E5
E11   Fish                 M      Planeta              E5
E12   Wood                 M      Planeta              E5
E13   Thorpe               F      Planeta              E5
E14   Gibson               M      Wiley
E15   Bergin               M      Wiley                E8
E16   Love                 F      Wiley                E8
E17   Owen                 F      Wiley                E8
E18   Haddock              F      Wiley                E8

18 rows selected.
```

Thanks

Comment: What if the publisher employs non-gender-binary workers? You're going to need a better table schema to represent this. #no-SexQL

Comment: What's your code at this point?

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple conditional aggregate:

```
select publishername, 
       count(case when gender = 'M' then 1 end) as Male, 
       count(case when gender = 'F' then 1 end) as Female
from employee 
group by publishername
order by publishername;
```

Comment: Does the `count (case ...)` work on anything different of Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @sergiol: that is most basic standard SQL. And (SQL based) database where that does *not* work is seriously broken.